# JSON Fatal Error foreach

Tags: php, html, foreach, json

I´ve got the following:

```
include('php/get_recipe_byID.php');
 $jsonstring1 = $recipe_byidarr;
 $recip = json_decode($recipe_byidarr, true);

print_r($recip);

foreach ($recip['Data']['Recipes'] as $key => $newrecipe) {
       // echo '<li>
         //         <a href="/recipe_search.php?id=' . $recipe['ID'] . '">';
         echo 'seas';
        echo  $newrecipe['TITLE'];
        echo '<br><br>';         
 }
```

When I call it in the browser, it tells me that

```
Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in /var/www/recipe_search.php on line 43
```

This is the line of the foreach loop.

$recip is the following:

```
{"Data":{"Recipes":{"Recipe_9":{"ID":"9","TITLE":"Schnitzel","TEXT":"Alex\u00b4s Hausmannskost","COUNT_PERSONS":"4","DURATION":"40","USER_ID":"1","DATE":"2011-09-16 00:00:00"}}},"Message":null,"Code":200}
```

Do anybody know where my mistake is?

Comment: It seems that since PHP5 you need to explicitly declare $recip as an array before using json_decode. Add the line `$recip = array();` before json_decode. Just a suggestion from what I'm seeing on Google :)

Comment: I already tried, that doesn´t helped

Answer (score 1):

Just try it:

```
$taskSeries = $array['Data']['Recipes']['Recipe_'.$_GET['id']];
if(array_key_exists('TITLE', $taskSeries)) {
    $taskSeries = array($taskSeries);
}
foreach($taskSeries as $task) {
    $title = $task['TITLE'];
    // do something with $title and other
}
```

Comment: so you mean it can be any id instead of _9 OR it will be like _1, _2, _3...and so on?

Comment: Why not? With `foreach ($recip['Data']['Recipes']['Recipe_' . $_GET['id']] as $key => $newrecipe){
        echo   $newrecipe['TITLE'] ;
 } `
But I still have the same error!

Comment: just remove the $key => and access by only ** foreach ($recip['Data']['Recipes']['Recipe_'. $_GET['id']] as $newrecipe) **

Comment: Ok, thanks for your attempt! I still get the same error at the row `$taskSeries = $array['Data']['Recipes']['Recipe_'.$_GET['id']];`

Comment: I think you should change your format of recips_9 to recips9 or like any other.

Comment: Sorry but I can´t believe that this is the problem, that isn´t possible.. it´s just formatting